# Solr new HttpSolrClient.Builder( str ) causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, maven, solr, swagger

Having problems with Sorl. when trying to run the following line of code:

```
HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder( "http://localhost:8983/solr/core" ).build();
```

I get the following error: 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

```
org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultHttpClient
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:211)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:228)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$Builder.build(HttpSolrClient.java:890)
```

I read on a couple posts that it could be a dependency issue with Maven since both Swagger and Sorl use httpClient. I moved my dependencies to the same pom and I wrapped dependencies within the `dependencymanagement` tag.

After doing this I ran the command: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

Looking at the tree, it is clear that the duplicate dependency is removed. However, i still get the same error.

Using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that Swagger is pulling in an earlier version of the library.

It looks like [SystemDefaultHttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultHttpClient.html) has only existed since version 4.2.

Does `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` show the same versions of http client in both cases?

Comment: Correct! took me some time to figure this out but it is exactly what you mentioned in your response. Thanks!